# ElementNotInteractableException and StaleElementReferenceException scraping website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, binance

I'm trying to scrape the contents in each link on this website: [binance listings](https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48)

However the code keeps throwing ElementNotInteractableException or StaleElementReferenceException. And when i try to deal with the error, i get thrown into this constant loop of new errors. This is my first time using Selenium, so any help would be deeply appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import  StaleElementReferenceException
import re 
import datetime

# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver (change the path to your WebDriver)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the webpage with your HTML content
driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48")

# Wait for the cookie consent pop-up to appear and then accept it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
cookie_consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'onetrust-banner-sdk')))
cookie_consent.click()
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# Click on the accept button
accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
# accept_button.send_keys("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", accept_button)
accept_button.click()


# link = None
# Find all div elements within the specified class
div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-148156o .css-1tl1y3y')
timeout = 20
# Extract links and titles from the div elements
for div_element in div_elements:
    # Create a WebDriverWait instance with expected conditions
    div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-148156o .css-1tl1y3y')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    try: 
        # Define a function to perform the action and return True
        # def click_checkout_link(driver):
            # global link
        link_element = div_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")  # Find the link element
        # link_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')))  # Click the link
        link = link_element.get_attribute('href')  # Get the "href" attribute
        print("Link: ", link)
        link_element.click()
        meta_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//meta[@name="description"]'))
    )
        content = meta_element.get_attribute('content')
        content = content.split(" ")
        # print("OG: ", content)
        content = [string for string in content if string.isupper() or string[0].isnumeric()] 
        content = tuple(content)
        print(content)
        timestamp = None
        date = None
        for string in content:
            if ":" in string:
                timestamp = string
            else: 
                try:
                    if datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d"):
                        date = string
                except ValueError:
                    continue
        print("Date: ", date)
        print("Time: ", timestamp)
        # Use the until method to wait for the condition to be met
        # link_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')))
        # link_element.click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        # Handle the StaleElementReferenceException (if needed)
        print("Element is stale, handle this case if necessary")
        print(e)
        continue
    # link = div_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
    
    # title = div_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'head > title').text

    # Click on the link to navigate to the linked page
    # link_url = link.get_attribute('href')
    # # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
    # print(f"Link: {link_url}")

    # Wait for the page to load (you can adjust the sleep time)
    time.sleep(2)

    # try:
        # Find and extract data from the linked page
    

    time.sleep(2)  # Sleep for a while before going back (you can adjust this)

    # Go back to the main page
    driver.back()

# Close the WebDriver when done
driver.quit()
```

I've tried going through the same issues on StackOverflow and using try and except blocks to catch NoSuchElementException by using

```
accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
```

and

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
cookie_consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'onetrust-banner-sdk')))
```

However when i try using `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located` for this line `link_element = div_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")  # Find the link element` i get to the wrong website     (binance.com) i have no idea why thats happening, it only happens if i use the wait.until() functions. It's supposed go back to the original website after scraping the individual links.

Also i don't get this error `ElementNotInteractableException` when i'm running debugging mode. I know `StaleElementReferenceException` it's something to do with relocating the same element after refreshing website when going back to the list of links, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `ElementNotInteractableException` you can use native JS click using JS executor.

`StaleElementReferenceException` exception you are getting as far as when you init `for in` loop, div_elements array are not re-inited by assigning new value to it, so you get old element reference.

To avoid this you can use `for in range` where you re-init array and get array elements by index.

```py
# previous code until getting div elements
div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-148156o .css-1tl1y3y')
timeout = 20
for i in range(len(div_elements)):
    div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-148156o .css-1tl1y3y')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    link_element = div_elements[i].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a") 
    link = link_element.get_attribute('href') 
    print("Link: ", link)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', link_element)
# your further code
```